# Show each name property of all the objects in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new at PHP and sessions. For a small project for school. How do i view only the name property of each object stored in a session variable?
I tried using foreach and then using $log->name to only get the name property, but it gives me a "Warning: Attempt to read property "name" on string in".

This is where i add new object to session variable:

```html
<?php

class Log
{
    public $name;
    public $location;
    public $activity;
}



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    session_start();

    $new_log = new Log;
    $new_log->name = $_POST['name'];
    $new_log->location = $_POST['location'];
    $new_log->activity = $_POST['activity'];

    $_SESSION['logs'][] = serialize($new_log);
    header('Location: data.php');
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="lead">Mensen aanmelden</p>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <!-- Vul de form tag aan zodat deze informatie naar process.php zal gepost worden -->
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <hr>
        <input type="radio" name="location" value="inside"> Binnen<br>
        <input type="radio" name="location" value="outside"> Buiten
        <hr>
        <input type="radio" name="activity" value="drinks"> Drinken<br>
        <input type="radio" name="activity" value="dance"> Dansen
        <hr>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Voeg toe">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is where i want to view each name of the object:

```html
<?php

session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION['logs'] as $log) {
    echo $log ->name. "<br>";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="index.php">return</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. Why serialize? 2. Why you're overwriting $_SESSION['logs'] instead of adding a new element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$_SESSION['logs'][] = serialize($new_log);
```